# Finding folders that occupy a lot of disk space

Tags: linux, bash, shell

```
du -cha --max-depth=1 / | grep -E "M|G"
```

I used this and it couldn't find the large folder containing 100000+ files and taking 890 GB. How come? Is there an issue with this command? I only found a 16GB folder with it. I think the folder that took 890 GB of disk space was inside /home/bestseller/project/v3.3.1/cached-images.

Comment: How do you know it's 890 GB? It may be your `du` printed `T`, not `G`. Especially if there are other files in `/home` that add to the number; but even without them [it may be so](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/120311/108618). Have you run sole `du -cha --max-depth=1 /` to check what your `grep` probably got?

Comment: Nope, I didn't, but I was surprised I didn't find the folder I wanted.

Comment: Well, this is a reasonable [*sanity* check](http://catb.org/jargon/html/S/sanity-check.html). :)

Comment: Not an answer but I find GUI tools to be WAY more helpful finding where my space is going.  I am a shell guy [but GUIs have their place](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_Usage_Analyzer#/media/File:GNOME_Disk_Usage_Analyzer_Tree_View.png).

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas I'm a shell guy too. You are right. For me it's not about GUI, it's about being interactive. E.g. I run `ncdu` in a tmux pane (so I can investigate details in another pane, if needed), it works well for me, no GUI needed. Regardless if one prefers GUI or terminal-based interactive tools, `du` is inferior in interactive usage. It's a useful non-interactive tool.